# How to configure Vite to allow JSX syntax in JS files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, vite, esbuild

Vite does not allow usage of JSX syntax within .js files by default.

I have already renamed my files to `.jsx` (or `.tsx`), but I have external dependencies that I cannot rename.

Example error from Vite:

```
✘ [ERROR] The JSX syntax extension is not currently enabled

    node_modules/somelib/src/someFile.js:122:11:
      122 │     return <div/>
```

How can I configure Vite to support JSX expressions in all .js files?

Answer (score 15):

The `vite.config.js` below makes Vite/Vitest treat `*.js` files as JSX to avoid errors like:

> Error: Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content
> contains invalid JS syntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name
> the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.

**vite.config.js**

```js
import { defineConfig, transformWithEsbuild } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    {
      name: 'treat-js-files-as-jsx',
      async transform(code, id) {
        if (!id.match(/src\/.*\.js$/))  return null

        // Use the exposed transform from vite, instead of directly
        // transforming with esbuild
        return transformWithEsbuild(code, id, {
          loader: 'jsx',
          jsx: 'automatic',
        })
      },
    },
    react(),
  ],

  optimizeDeps: {
    force: true,
    esbuildOptions: {
      loader: {
        '.js': 'jsx',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: The accepted answer = https://stackoverflow.com/a/74620428/4200446 didn't work for me. However this solution worked. In my case, I needed to use "tsx", not "jsx".

Answer (score 11):

You can change esbuild configuration to treat all js files as jsx with the `loader` option:

```js
// vite.config.ts
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(() => ({
  esbuild: {
    loader: "tsx", // OR "jsx"
    include: [
      // Add this for business-as-usual behaviour for .jsx and .tsx files
      "src/**/*.jsx",
      "src/**/*.tsx",
      "node_modules/**/*.jsx",
      "node_modules/**/*.tsx",

      // Add the specific files you want to allow JSX syntax in
      "src/LocalJsxInJsComponent.js",
      "node_modules/bad-jsx-in-js-component/index.js",
      "node_modules/bad-jsx-in-js-component/js/BadJSXinJS.js",
      "node_modules/bad-jsx-in-js-component/ts/index.ts",
      "node_modules/bad-jsx-in-js-component/ts/BadTSXinTS.ts",

      // --- OR ---

      // Add these lines to allow all .js files to contain JSX
      "src/**/*.js",
      "node_modules/**/*.js",

      // Add these lines to allow all .ts files to contain JSX
      "src/**/*.ts",
      "node_modules/**/*.ts",
    ],
  },
}));
```

Note: there is a performance penalty for loading .js files with the .jsx loader.

Answer taken from this [discussion in Vite's GitHub](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/3448#discussioncomment-747542), Which marks the incorrect (and older) answer as the "correct" one.

### Update March 2023

The original answer did not work correctly for `vite build`, only for `vite dev`. The current version works for both with `vite@^4.0.0`

Here is an [example repo](https://github.com/soof-golan/so-vite-jsx-in-js) you can clone and test the solution.

### Update November 2023

Vite 5.0 was released, this might not be relevant anymore, edits + corrections welcome.

Comment: This seems to work for me when running `vite serve`, but not when I run `vite build`.

Comment: @NickyMuller, updated to support `vite build`

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to get the config in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74620428/4200446) to work as-is.  I needed to add `include` and `exclude` keys to the `esbuild` config for some reason.

Building on [this comment](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/3448#discussioncomment-5288419) on the Vite discussion board, I was able to get this config file working for both `vite serve` and `vite build`.  (Well, "working" as in not complaining about JSX in `.js` files anymore.  Vite is still complaining about some CJS modules...)

```js
// vite.config.js
import fs from "node:fs";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import * as esbuild from "esbuild";

const sourceJSPattern = /\/src\/.*\.js$/;
const rollupPlugin = (matchers) => ({
  name: "js-in-jsx",
  load(id) {
    if (matchers.some(matcher => matcher.test(id))) {
      const file = fs.readFileSync(id, { encoding: "utf-8" });
      return esbuild.transformSync(file, { loader: "jsx" });
    }
  }
});

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react()
  ],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [
        rollupPlugin([sourceJSPattern])
      ],
    },
    commonjsOptions: {
      transformMixedEsModules: true,
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      loader: {
        ".js": "jsx",
      },
    },
  },
  esbuild: {
    loader: "jsx",
    include: [sourceJSPattern],
    exclude: [],
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when migrating from CRA to Vite. Based on the example in [this comment](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/769#issuecomment-777843876) on Github I was able to treat all `.js` files as `jsx`:

### vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({

  // rest of configuration

  esbuild: {
    include: /\.js$/,
    exclude: [],
    loader: 'jsx',
  },
})
```

If you want to treat all combinations of `.js`, `.jsx`, `.ts`, and `.tsx` files as `jsx`, you might want to use the following `include` pattern:

```
esbuild: {
  include: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
  exclude: [],
  loader: 'jsx',
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to - @Maksim Shamihulau  This answer worked for me for latest versions of Vite & React and used Tailwind Css also and it started working https://stackoverflow.com/a/76726872/23205457  :-

```
import { defineConfig, transformWithEsbuild } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    {
      name: 'treat-js-files-as-jsx',
      async transform(code, id) {
        if (!id.match(/src\/.*\.js$/))  return null

        // Use the exposed transform from vite, instead of directly
        // transforming with esbuild
        return transformWithEsbuild(code, id, {
          loader: 'jsx',
          jsx: 'automatic',
        })
      },
    },
    react(),
  ],

  optimizeDeps: {
    force: true,
    esbuildOptions: {
      loader: {
        '.js': 'jsx',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

simply just updated the vite.config.js file, added allow file types in react plugin.

`export default defineConfig({ plugins: [react({ include: /\.(mdx|js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/ })], });`