# npm Installation Fails in Docker Container During Build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm, vite

In summary, while attempting to build a Django, React, and Vite application, I'm encountering an issue with `npm` installation within a Docker container.

Initially, both the `npm` & `Node.js` installations were not executing in the container. However, I resolved the Node.js failure after adding two `COPY` commands referenced in my `Dockerfile`.

However, even after trying many configurations, the `npm` failure persists.

**Checking `Node.js` installation inside the container:**

```
% docker exec -it docktest-web-1 node -v
  v14.21.3
```

**Checking `npm` installation inside the container:**

```
% docker exec -it docktest-web-1 npm -v
  OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "npm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

**The build still completes successfully, but `npm` is not installed in the container.*

---

The relevant aspects of my configuration are as follows:

**`Dockerfile`**

```
# Use the official Node.js image for frontend build
FROM node:14 as frontend-build

# Set the working directory for the frontend build
WORKDIR /frontend

# Copy only the package.json to take advantage of Docker caching mechanism
COPY frontend/package.json ./

# Copy the rest of the frontend code to the container
COPY frontend/ .

# Install frontend dependencies
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install vite -g
RUN npm install npm@latest -g

# Build the frontend
RUN npm run build

# Create main container for Django and PostgreSQL
FROM python:3

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules

# Without these two lines,the Node.js installation failed as well
COPY --from=frontend-build /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=frontend-build /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/

# Set the working directory for Django
WORKDIR /code

# Copy the backend requirements and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the frontend build from the previous stage to the working directory of the main container
COPY --from=frontend-build /frontend/ /code/frontend/

# Copy the frontend
COPY . /code/
```

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - /code/frontend/  # Exclude frontend folder from being mounted to avoid conflicts
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

---

**Addendum – Update 8/1:**

1. If visiting this post with similar issues, after reviewing the "Accepted Answer" the `create-vite` templates in the [Vite.js GitHub Repository](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/create-vite) are very helpful for configuring `package.json` with `Vite` and `React` dependencies. Initial link suggested by [@Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) linking to [Vite Documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project).
2. To resolve the following `Vite`/`React` error (*below*), the suggested solutions in this post: [Configure Vite to Allow JSX Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74620427/how-to-configure-vite-to-allow-jsx-syntax-in-js-files) proved very helpful as well:

```
[ERROR] The JSX syntax extension is not currently enabled
```

Comment: @Phil I am trying to use Vite to bundle React on the frontend, while using Django on the backend using a multi-stage build

Comment: That is a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) which results in a single image

Comment: That depends, are you trying to run these apps in a production-like configuration or are you trying to use this for development? Do you want to run the Vite dev-server or do you want to build the React app and serve it statically?

Comment: @Phil Currently for development, but wanted to run in a production-like configuration. Originally I was attempting to serve the React app statically with Django. However, I was not getting the benefit of Vite's HMR. I don't know if this was a configuration error or expected behavior in that config (I was *also* getting an `unexpected token error` when trying to serve the React files - unsure if it was related). However, since then, I had been trying to run the Vite dev-server to get the benefit of HMR, but I couldn't do that without installing npm.

Comment: Your `package.json` is missing all its `dependencies`. How did you generate it? I would use one of the existing [Vite templates](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project), eg `npm create vite@latest frontend -- --template react`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to run separate services for front-end and back-end. The issue is that you're producing a single image for both which will be difficult to manage.

I would set up separate compose services with their own build contexts for each. If you plan on supporting both development and production-like configurations, I'd recommend separate Docker and compose files too.

For example, this is a development configuration with volume mounts for your source code and running the Vite dev-server with HMR.

```bash
# ./frontend/Dockerfile.dev

FROM node:14-alpine # it's seriously time to upgrade https://endoflife.date/nodejs

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5173

COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install

# no need to copy other files since we'll volume-mount them

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev", "--", "--host"]
```

```bash
# ./Dockerfile.dev
# You may want to consider putting your backend code into its own folder too

FROM python:3

WORKDIR /code
EXPOSE 8000

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml
# ...

react:
  build:
    context: ./frontend
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
  ports:
    - "5173:5173"
  volumes:
    - ./frontend:/app
    - /app/node_modules

django:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  depends_on:
    - db
```

---

A production build would look more like your original `Dockerfile`, using a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) to compile your React app then copy it into Django's static serving directory (*note: I'm not a Python dev but it seems a fairly straight forward configuration based on [this article](https://medium.com/codex/deploying-react-through-djangos-static-files-part-1-dev-setup-8a3a7b93c809)*)

```bash
# Dockerfile

# Frontend build
FROM node:14-alpine AS frontend-build
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /build

COPY frontend/package*.json .
RUN npm ci

COPY frontend .
RUN npm run build

# Backend build
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
COPY --from=frontend-build /build/dist ./staticfiles # ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Comment: You seriously cannot begin to understand how grateful I am for your help...THIS IS IT!!! I've literally spent 20 working hours trying everything I could think of to get this running, and this is the answer! I know comments aren't meant for this, but I wanted to let you know how appreciative I am – I wish there was something I could do in return! Thank you so much!

Comment: @DAK probably too big to tackle in the comments but if you moved all the Django code into `./backend`, you'd use `context: ./backend` and `dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev`. I'd be no help diagnosing Django issues. Like I said, I'm no Python dev

Comment: Yeah no worries, it's more than likely a Django config issue since that's the docker-compose setup I've used. I'll figure it out – thanks again.