# React app using Vite could not be build Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, vite

I'm trying to build React web application using React native modules like react-native-toast-message. When the application is run in dev mode it works, but whet I try to build it, the following error occurs.

```
[commonjs--resolver] Unexpected token (15:12) in /node_modules/react-native-toast-message/lib/src/Toast.js
file: /Library/WebServer/Documents/loyalty-react-admin/node_modules/react-native-toast-message/lib/src/Toast.js:15:12
13:         hide
14:     }), [hide, show]));
15:     return (<ToastUI isVisible={isVisible} options={options} data={data} hide={hide} show={show} config={config}/>);
```

So I suppose that the problem is that JSX is not interpreted as the file is with .js extension, but maybe I do not succeed with the right configuration for this to happen.

The vite.config.ts looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

const extensions = [
  ".web.tsx",
  ".tsx",
  ".web.ts",
  ".ts",
  ".web.jsx",
  ".jsx",
  ".web.js",
  ".js",
  ".css",
  ".json",
];

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  esbuild: {
    loader: "tsx",
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    svgr()
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      loader: {
        '.js': 'tsx',
      },
      resolveExtensions: extensions,
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
      'react-native-maps': 'react-native-web-maps',
      '../Utilities/Platform': 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform',
      '../../Utilities/Platform': 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform',
      './Platform': 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform',
      path: "path-browserify",
    },
    extensions: extensions,
  },
  // define: {
  //   'process.env': process.env,
  // },
  define: {
    'process.<wbr>env': {}
  },
  server: {
    host: true,
  },
  base: './',
});
```

Comment: It seems like Vite is treating .js files as TypeScript files because you've set the loader to "tsx" in the esbuild configuration. 

try this:

esbuild: {
    loaders: {
      '.js': 'jsx', // Specify the loader for .js files as 'jsx'
    },
  },

Comment: @Kingalione thanks for your reply. Unfortunately changing it does not help too.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a solution for the moment. Related to this question: [How to configure Vite to allow JSX syntax in JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74620427/how-to-configure-vite-to-allow-jsx-syntax-in-js-files)

This is the new vite.config.js.

```
import { defineConfig, transformWithEsbuild } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

const extensions = [
  ".web.tsx",
  ".tsx",
  ".web.ts",
  ".ts",
  ".web.jsx",
  ".jsx",
  ".web.js",
  ".js",
  ".css",
  ".json",
];

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    {
      name: 'treat-js-files-as-jsx',
      async transform(code, id) {
        if(
          !id.includes('react-native-toast-message') &&
          !id.includes('react-native-vector-icons')
        ) return null;

        //if (!id.match(/src\/.*\.js$/)) return null

        // Use the exposed transform from vite, instead of directly
        // transforming with esbuild
        return transformWithEsbuild(code, id, {
          loader: 'jsx',
          jsx: 'automatic',
        })
      },
    },
    react(),
    svgr()
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    force: true,
    esbuildOptions: {
      loader: {
        '.js': 'jsx',
      },
      resolveExtensions: extensions,
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
      'react-native-maps': 'react-native-web-maps',
      '../Utilities/Platform': 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform',
      '../../Utilities/Platform': 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform',
      './Platform': 'react-native-web/dist/exports/Platform',
      path: "path-browserify",
    },
    extensions: extensions,
  },
  // define: {
  //   'process.env': process.env,
  // },
  define: {
    'process.<wbr>env': {}
  },
  server: {
    host: true,
  },
  base: './',
});
```